# Are these two function spaces identical?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let the function space $A$ denote all functions $f : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ such that, for some set $Z$ of Lebesgue measure zero, the derivative $f'$ exists on $[0, 1) \setminus Z$ and $|f'| = 1$ there.

Let the function space $B$ denote all functions $f : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ such that for all $a < b$ in $[0, 1)$, the portion $G_f(a,b) = \{(x,f(x)) ∈ \mathbb R^2 \mid a \le x < b\}$ of the graph of $f$ that lies above $[a, b)$ has Hausdorff $1$-measure $H_1(G_f(a,b))$ equal to $\sqrt 2(b - a)$.

(Note that we do not assume functions to be continuous.)

Does $A = B$?

Edit: The following is false, as was shown to me by Christian Remling by an easy application of the Cantor function:
"It is clear to me that $A$ is a subset of $B$." (Wrong!)

- So the real question is whether the reverse inclusion holds.

Comment: This wouldn't be that bad to use MathJax on.

Comment: I am studying MathJax, but am still such a beginner that I don't dare use it in a post yet.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about your MathJax being perfect! If you have some mistakes in your MathJax I'm sure people will be happy to help fix them. A good tip is that in future if you're wondering how to typeset something in MathJax you can look back at your older questions, or other people's questions, and click on "edit" to see how the MathJax is done.

Comment: IvD: Thanks for the editing — it looks much better now.

Comment: You don't even need to hit "Edit". You can right-click on any mathjax you see and select "Show Math As > TeX commands" to see how it was accomplished. Also helpful for quoting/modifying someone's complicated formula in your own comment or answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be a fat Cantor set, and let

$$ f(x) = x + \mathbf{1}_F(x). $$

Then for any $[a, b) \subseteq [0, 1)$,

\begin{align*}
G_f([a,b))
&= \{ (x, x) : x \in [a, b) \setminus F\} \cup \{(x, x+1) : x \in [a, b) \cap F \}
\end{align*}

and hence we get

\begin{align*}
H_1(G_f([a,b)))
&= \sqrt{2}\operatorname{Leb}([a, b) \setminus F) + \sqrt{2}\operatorname{Leb}([a, b) \cap F) \\
&= \sqrt{2}\operatorname{Leb}([a, b)) \\
&= \sqrt{2}(b - a).
\end{align*}

This shows that $f$ is a member of $B$.

On the other hand, $f$ is not differentiable at each point in $F$. Therefore, $f$ does not lie in $A$.

Comment: This looks very nice. In the second sentence, after the union sign ∪, should it read "x ∈ F" (not [a, b))? (And in the next-to-last sentence, should that read "*f* is a member of B" (not A)?

Comment: @DanAsimov, You are right. Darn, I didn't realize I made this much typos... Now they are fixed (or I hope so)!

Comment: Not a typo, but I have not seen the notation "Leb" before. Does it mean Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Dan, Indeed, yes :) It is sometimes used in probability theory.